# Should we mock models?

Tags: testing, mocking

We are having a debate at work and cannot find anything in the internet:

Is it a good practice to mock models? And why?

(Just clarifying, models as in per clean architecture definition)

Thanks

Comment: What kind of models?

Comment: Data models. As in the tradicional POJOs in Java.